The meaning of "snack it up"
What is the meaning of "snack it up"? Does it roughly mean "eat it up"? The context here has to do with food. Thank you!

It's one-off wordplay, in the context of a program whereby "Kids learn the basics of kitchen safety and healthy food preparation while making easy snacks." Maybe a slight echo of snap it up (advice to quickly grab a bargain).

This isn't a common phrase in speech or writing, but I see that it is being used here as an event title. It roughly means "have lots of snacks!"
There are several more common phrases that follow this pattern of [verb] + "it up", and this is playing on those. Here are some of the phrases that this comes from and their most common meanings:

Eat it up - (like you mentioned!) - "eat very quickly and completely" OR "consume figuratively, such as with information"
Live it up - "enjoy life," "indulge in luxuries" - for example: "If I was rich, I would really live it up."
Light it up - "turn on all the lights" OR "ignite a fire/explosive" OR "add figurative brightness to a space (such as by smiling)"
Pump it up - "add air/water to a container so that it inflates (e.g., a balloon)" OR "put more energy into what you're doing."

The common thread here is that all of them are talking about doing lots of something or doing something to an extreme. They are primarily used in positive contexts (although can be negative as well).
Non-Related Examples
But, like all things in English, there are lots of exceptions to this rule. Here are a few instances of [verb] + "it up" that don't mean "do this thing to the extreme." You're welcome to look for or ask for definitions on any of these that you would like.

Shake it up
Give it up
Turn it up
Keep it up
Mix it up
Chop it up
Mess it up


Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations!

+1 Wanna come over and hang out with us? We're not doing anything special, just gonna yuck it up.
